# Show a notification to an specific user only with pusher

Tags: php, pusher

I've been following this tutorial but if I were to add this code to my application it would show the notification to all users viewing my application. I wonder if it is possible to change the code so that the the notification is shown only to a specific user.

http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible

Comment: thank you, is it complicated? can you give me an example?

Comment: use `if`. `if (the user is specific) { show a notification }`

Comment: $pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$data = array('message' => $message);
$pusher->trigger('my_notifications', 'notification', $data);

Comment: you need to learn how to program using php. We won't do your work for you.

Comment: I know how to program in php, the thing that i do not know is where do i have to put the conditional? if($_SESSION["user"]=="$user_id"){ }

Comment: and what kind of answer do you expect? You should put it in the place where you need to call the `Pusher`

Comment: `if($_SESSION["user"]=="Raul"){

$pusher->trigger('my_notifications', 'notification', $data);

}`it does not work, it show the notification  everyone -> [http://cryptic-mountain-9559.herokuapp.com/push/examples/demon.php?user=Raul

Comment: if that code is called for every user - then every user is `Raul`

Comment: This question requires some Pusher domain knowledge; mainly that [Pusher](http://pusher.com) uses [channels](http://pusher.com/docs/channels) to route information from the server to the client. I've updated the question to clarify. Could it please be reopened?

Comment: try reading this:
http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users